# Is GenyMotion officially supported by Google?

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, genymotion, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to find alternative to the native Android Emulators which are too slow to efficiently work. Is GenyMotion officially supported by Google? Will all/most APIs work on it?

Comment: Yes. The current and future SDK APIs for Android.

Comment: yes, its built from the official AOSP sources and all the SDK API are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's separate product, yet they use official AOSP sources to build their images. The downside of not being supported by google is lack of Google Apps on their images, so if you need i.e. Google Play Store or other things you may need to look for additional files on the net. But these are available w/o much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

No Genymotion is not officially supported by Google. But it is your best option as Android Default Emulators are slow and time consuming.
Additional things needed for using Genymotion are: You need a plugin for Android Studio, You need to install Google play services. I believe thats all. Genymotion is the best you can get.